# Perform JOIN on three or four different tables in Laravel syntax

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel, laravel-4

```
TABLES X(ID,A_ID)A(ID,B_ID),B(ID,C_ID),C(ID,D_ID)D(id,VALUE)
```

I want to retrieve the value of `D` table using laravel syntax on basis of `X` table Id and perform a `JOIN` with other tables.

Please post answers only in laravel syntax. In other format I can do. I am new to it so.

```
X::select('value')
->join('a', 'X.a_id', '=', 'a.id')
->join('b', 'a.b_id', '=', 'b.id')
->join('c', 'b.c_id', '=', 'c.id')
->join('d', 'c.d_id', '=', 'd.id')
->where('x.id', '=', $val)
->get();
```

But it is not working. please provide me proper solution. Right now I am using PHP logic to get the value, rather than optimise the query.

Comment: `But it is not working.` What not working exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, but this is the basic:

```
$rows = DB::table('shares')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'shares.user_id')
        ->join('follows', 'follows.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('follows.follower_id', '=', 3)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

[doc](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins)

Try this:

```
DB::table('X')
   ->join('a', 'X.a_id', '=', 'a.id')
   ->join('b', 'a.b_id', '=', 'b.id')
   ->join('c', 'b.c_id', '=', 'c.id')
   ->join('d', 'c.d_id', '=', 'd.id')
   ->select('D.value')
   ->where('x.id', '=', $val)
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = X::select('a.value', 'd.*')
    ->join('a', 'x.a_id', '=', 'a.id')
    ->join('b', 'a.b_id', '=', 'b.id')
    ->join('c', 'b.c_id', '=', 'c.id')
    ->join('d', 'c.d_id', '=', 'd.id')
    ->where('x.id', '=', $val)
    ->get();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    # code...
}
```